# Provider login logout flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, state-management

I am trying to create a simple authentication flow using Provider. I have three pages :

1. LoginPage
2. OnboardingPage
3. HomePage

The flow of this app is:

1. if a user opens the app for the first time, he/she will be redirected to the onboarding then to login to home.
2. For the second time user, the app first checks the login status and redirected to either log in -> home or straight to home page.

Here is my setup in code :

**main.dart**

```
void main() {
  runApp(MultiProvider(providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider<StorageHelper>(create: (_) => StorageHelper()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthProvider>(create: (_) => AuthProvider()),
  ], child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<AuthProvider>(builder: (final BuildContext context,
        final AuthProvider authProvider, final Widget child) {
        print(authProvider.isAuthenticated); // this is false whenever I //click the logout from category(or other pushed pages) but the below ternary //operation is not executing
      return MaterialApp(
          title: 'My Poor App',
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: ThemeData(
            primaryColor: Color(0xff29c17e),
            visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
          ),
          home: authProvider.isAuthenticated ? HomeScreen() : LoginScreen(),
          onGenerateRoute: Router.onGenerateRoute,
        );
    });
  }
}
```

**LoginScreen.dart**

```
class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final authProvider = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                await authProvider.emailLogin('user@email.com', 'pass');
              },
              child: Text('Login'))),
    );
  }
}
```

**HomeScreen.dart**

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final auth = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: MaterialButton(
                elevation: 2,
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => CategoryScreen()));
                },
                child: Text('Reset')),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**AuthProvider.dart**

```
class AuthProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isAuthenticated = false;

  bool get isAuthenticated => _isAuthenticated;

  set isAuthenticated(bool isAuth) {
    _isAuthenticated = isAuth;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future emailLogin(String email, String password) async {
    isAuthenticated = true;
  }

  Future logout() async {
    isAuthenticated = false;
  }
}
```

If i logout from home page using `Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context).logout()` it works fine. But if I `push` or `pushReplacement` a new route and try to logout from the new route (just say I navigated from home to category page and try to logout from there), I am not redirected to LoginPage. If I print the value of `isAuthenticated` it prints false but the consumer is not listening or at least not reacting to the variable change.

Please don't mark this question as duplicate, I have searched many other similar questions and none of them worked for my case.

**Edit:**
**CategoryScreen.dart**

```
class CategoryScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            final auth = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false);
            auth.logout();
            // print(auth.isAuthenticated);
          },
          child: Text('Category Logout'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: The widget tree of first time login page]

[image: The widget tree of home page]

[image: The widget tree after the navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(CategoryScreen)]

Comment: I guess the problem is in your `Navigator`. When you logout from the `Category`, use [Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/pushAndRemoveUntil.html) or [Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushNamedAndRemoveUntil.html) after you do the logout

Comment: @Alok have checked that and that didn't work.

Comment: Are you stuck at the same page only when you try doing logout from `CategoryPage`?

Comment: @Alok . yes every other page which I push using navigator and try to logout from there, it just stays still. The consumer is not reacting at all. And I don't get any error in console.

Comment: @Alok I have updated the CategoryScreen snippet. Do I have to use `notifyListener` there? I already change the `isAuthenticated` value using setter and setter is using notifyListner.

Comment: Use `notifyListener()` in `logout()` method in `AuthProvider`

Comment: @Alok  Still not working. I have printed the value inside consumer and it gives false whenever I click logout but I am amazed why it is not working in that logic

Comment: After your logout, why don't you do `Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil()`? Couldn't see that in the code in the `CategoryScreen`

Comment: @Alok If I don't misunderstand the provider, I assumed that the consumer must react to that change and execute the logic inside it. Your suggestions seem working but the problem is I have navigated to the login page but after that, if I hit the login button it stopped working.

Comment: Check out the answer Suraj. I hope that would work for you :) Let me know, else, we will look for some other changes. But I have given you the bigger picture on this

Answer (score 1):

I guess your problem is that you did not use `Consumer` for the `logout`, in your `home` in the `MaterialApp`. Just see, that if it works out for you

**main.dart**

```
// needs to listen to the changes, to make changes 
home: Consumer<AuthProvider>(
  builder: (context, authProvider, child){
     return authProvider.isAuthenticated ? HomeScreen() : LoginScreen();
  }
)
```

Since, `Consumer` was not there for your `home`, even if the value was being changed, it was not able to work on updating the view for you as per the Provider.

Comment: The same login page or home page under the consumer widget is replaced by the new page pushed by navigator directly below MaterialApp. Now I lost the consumer widget in the tree.

Comment: Use your Consumer for `Home`, not for `MaterialApp` @SurajKhanal

Comment: Exactly implemented as your answer.